# Kendo grid rounds figure on edit?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendonumerictextbox

[image]

I am using Kendo grid for editing data. My problem is that when I edit a cell, it rounds the figure to two decimal places, even if the format of the cell is 4 decimal places.

Why its behaving like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might add an `editor` function for that column. Something like:

```
columns: [
    ...
    { 
        field: "Value",
        width: 200, 
        format: "{0:##.####}", 
        editor: function(container, options) {
            // create an input element
            $("<input name='" + options.field + "'/>")
            .appendTo(container)
            .kendoNumericTextBox({
                decimals: 4
            });
        }
    },
    ...
]
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/p92d1q8z/